# Why does my text overflow right away?

Tags: text, page-layout

Why am I getting the text overflow symbol, when there isn't any overflow? When I create a text box over a photo I have placed and just type in 1 letter it immediately puts a text overflow symbol on the text box.  If I move the box over to the side, the text flow symbol goes away.

Comment: Hi Barb X, welcome to GD.SE! What application are you using? Do you have text wrap put on the text box? Do you have a line break in the text box? There isn't enough information here for us to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the photo have a text wrap set to it and your text box is not "ignore text wrap" checked. This force text to be moved "outside" and in result you get "overflow" status.